# Strange behavior in Excel when counting Work Hours and Work Super Hours.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I composed the next Worksheet in order to count my Workhours.

[image: Work Hours Worksheet] Other solutions proposed over the internet would not work, since the Workhours amount per day was not fixed at first. The problem makes its appearrance sometimes when the "Total Work Hours" equal the "Normal Work Hours". When i try to format the Super Hours Cells using conditions, i don't get the correct result. The equality seems not to be the case.
[image: Conditional format]

Cell K9: Negative or very big date and time values are displayed as pound signs (###)

The following information are important:

1. The Cells A4:B500, F4, F5 are formated like: Hour 13:30
2. The Cells J7:R9 are formated like: Custom [h]:mm
3. J7: =SUM($C4:$C34) and respectively Cells K7,L7...
4. J8: =J4*$F$5 and respectively Cells K8,L8...
5. J9: =IF(J$7>=J$8;J$7-J$8;J$8-J$7) and respectively Cells K9,L9...

I would like to know why this happens and if there is a solution or a different approach.

Comment: Cells I9, M9, N9, O9, P9 and Q9 are OK. Cells J9, K9 and L9 should be green with value "0:00".

Comment: Thank you for the quick response pnuts. It seems you have a point. It was just not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform math operations in Excel you will sometimes get floating point errors. They come about because Excel is limited to 15 digit precision so significant digits after 15 are ignored.

Times in Excel are all percentages of days. Computers calculate in binary so all those decimals have to be converted to binary before the math operation and the result has to be converted back to decimal.

For example, something as simple as 0.1 in binary is like Pi in decimal - it isn't a finite number.

Do math on those converted numbers and there are going to be rounding errors.

If you change the format of K9 to General, you will probably find it's a very small negative number expressed in scientific notation.

Rounding the result in K9 to something greater than 4 to allow for 1440 minutes in a day, should get rid of the error.

Comment: Good explanation. Having said that, if you multiply 8 by 19 or add it 19 times, you should get the same answer even if 8 hours isn't an exact binary number. I think the trouble comes from the (very hard to read) formula for column C which involves B10-A10-$F$4 - this will only be approximately the same as 8 hours for reasons explained in the answer.

Comment: @TomSharpe both 8 and 19 return finite binary numbers. It's when you get past the decimal point that it becomes uncertain.

Comment: _if you multiply 8 by 19 or add it 19 times, you should get the same answer even if 8 hours isn't an exact binary number_ The answer is no, and that's why OP got negative number in K9

Comment: Thank you @MarkFitzgerald. This was really the case. Rounding the "Total Work Hours" and the "Normal Work Hours" to the 5th decimal, solved the problem.

Comment: OK I may be wrong about addition vs multiplication but am right about the source of the error - will post a demonstration later.

Answer (score 0):

OK well I consider myself duly corrected in my statement that repeated addition should give the same answer as multiplication. I was just trying to say that it was deterministic (same calculation should give same answer) but it came out wrong.

So it is very possible that multiplication vs addition is the reason for the discrepancy, but it can also come from the way that the time constants were defined and later combined as you can see from this demo:-

[image]

The last decimal place of B6 is different from B8 so the equality test fails.

This is in Excel 2007: I couldn't reproduce the behaviour in Excel 2003 or Excel 2010.